# Linq query to get values from three different entities into matrix

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework, lambda

I am trying to write Linq query to get data from three tables using EF and having hard time with it....What I have is

```
tblUsername
userId      username
---------------------
 1          jadam
 2          janeb
 3          peterk
 4          rickd
```

Second table has name of the columns

```
tablcolumns
=============
colId     colname
-----------------
  1        Name
  2        Monday
  3        Tuesday
  4        Wednesday
  5        Thursday
  6        Friday
  7        Saturday
  8        Sunday
```

Third table has values

```
tblSchedule
==================
id   userId   colId   hrs
--------------------------
1      2       3       4
2      3       7       7.5
3      1       8       2
```

I am trying to write Linq statement so that my output looks like this

```
public class model 
{
    public int colId {get; set;}
    public string colname {get; set;}
    public virtual IQueryable<detailsmodel> detailsmodel {get; set;}

{ 

public class detailsmodel
{
     public int userId {get; set;}
     public string username {get; set:}
     pubic double hrs {get; set;}
}
```

Result should have following structure

```
Name  Monday  Tuesday  Wednesday Thursday Friday Saturday Sunday 
jadam   2
janeb           4
peterk                                            7.5
rickd
```

I tried this but it doesn't work

```
var result= (DbContext.Set<tablcolumns>() 
            .Select(c=> new  model()
               {
                  colId=c.colId,
                  colname=c.colname,
                  detailsmodel= (from e in DbContext.Set<tblSchedule>(){
                                  join a in DbContext.Set<tblUsername>() 
                                      on e.userId equals a.userId
                                  Select new detailsmodel()
                                   {userId=a.username,
                                    username=a.username,
                                    hrs= e.hrs}
                                  }) });
```

The above query gives me values under one columns rest of the columns are empty. 
Please let me know how to get the Linq query right to get the result as shown in the above in result structure.

Comment: your query may not even compile, where is the reference of `q`?

Comment: talking about the idea, you're almost close to the solution, just use some `where` to filter the `detailsmodel` so that only the subset of the result corresponds to the current `c.colId`

Comment: In your EF model, you should set up navigation properties from tblcolumns to tblSchedule, and tblSchedule to tblUsername.  Then your query becomes: `var result=DbContext.tablcolumns.Include(c=>c.Schedules).Include(c=>c.Schedules.User);`

Comment: Changed q to a it was a typo. Thanks

Comment: This is a pivot operation. LINQ doesn't have any built-in tricks for that.